# how to make executable for mac and ubuntu in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I've never made a program into an executable for mac or ubuntu , and I've been looking into how to do this for some time now but didn`t got any results. I have been able to build my game for android, ios, windows(.exe) but dont have any idea about mac osx(.app file) or ubuntu (.deb file ).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using eclipse, you could just export as a cross-platform jar (which would then work for mac, linux and windows)

Eclipse makes that really easy: File -> Export ... -> Java -> Runnable Jar File. There may be additional steps required to include assets like your app's images and sounds into this .jar file.

Btw, how did you turn it into a windows exe anyway?